# Validate and submit ipa to AppStore without source

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store, submission, ipa

I need to send an ipa to the client to submit it to the App Store (he has given me his .p12 key and certificate, together with the provisioning profile).

When it was XCode 3.x (submission = upload through webbrowser), it is an easy process. But with XCode 4, how can I do this?

- I cannot validate and submit the app myself because I don't have my client's username and password for itunesconnect.
- He doesn't have the project, but just the ipa that I built, so he cannot archive/validate/submit it neither.

Is there any way he can import the ipa into the XCode organizer to validate and submit it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must build for device using the appropriate certificate/provisionning,
Then go to products, you find the .app file, choose "show in finder"
Zip the .app file and send it to your client.

Once you've done this, your client must use "Application loader" to submit/updload the binary/application.

"Application Loader" is an utility installed with Xcode.
In general you find it in the path "xcode/Applications/Utilities"

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Application Loader.

Comment: there is no option for adding our `.ipa` file in "Application Loader".

Comment: For anyone having the same question as @I-droid : an IPA file is just a ZIP file. So just unzip it, and you'll find the .app inside the Payload directory.

Comment: Also new versions of Application Loader accept ipa files

Answer (score 5):

Your client could use the application loader to upload the ipa.

You should first select `Deliver Your App` and not `Open Package` which is misleading.