# Upload IPA with Application Loader

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, ipa

I have an IPA and would like to upload it with *Application Loader*. But when I click "Open package" in Application Loader, I cannot select the IPA file, it is greyed out.

How can I upload this IPA file to iTunes Connect with Application Loader?

Comment: I might have signed it with an AdHoc Distribution Profile. But shouldn't this at least allow me to open the IPA and get an error afterwards? And BTW, I had archives in Xcode Organizer which were signed with an AdHoc Distribution Profile which could easily be uploaded through Xcode, it just re-signed.

Comment: Okay ZIP the app bundloe and wallah! it will work

Comment: I tried that yesterday but I still could not select the file in the open dialog. I can hardly believe that Application Loader looks at all files shown in the open dialog and only makes those selectable which meet some criteria other than file extension. Something is strange here. Are you sure you just zipped your IPA and could open it in Application Loader afterwards?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is wrong to click the "Open package" button. Use "Deliver Your App" instead. For that feature to be available, online at [itunesconnect.apple.com](http://itunesconnect.apple.com) a new version must be created which accepts the wanted IPA.

Then the IPA can be uploaded, which is a ZIPped Application.

Comment: Hi Fabb. Could you please tell me what is a Zipped application? Do you mean that I have do "export as Xcode archive" first and then zip the .xcarchive file? Please clarify.

Comment: The `.ipa` is what you need. No need to zip it. The `.ipa` actually just is a `.zip` file with a different extension. You could rename it to `YourAppName.zip` and unzip it to have a peek inside.

Comment: Thanks much Fabb!! I wanted to know whether I should upload a .xcarchive file or .ipa file to application loader? In the Xcode organizer page, we have to options. One is "export as xcode archive" and another one is "save for ad-hoc or enterprise distribution". Which one should I use?

Comment: Looks like the third option is gone in Xcode 6. Sorry, I don't know as I generate my ipas via commandline

Comment: Thanks Fabb! May i know how you are doing that from command line. I m eager to learn that.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for iOS projects, you only need to submit a .app(generate by Xcode) which is zipped.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what an IPA is, apart from some additional files in the IPA?

Comment: Can you search here for the .app file ? ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName/Build/Products .. Zip that

Comment: No, as Jenkins created the IPA on another building machine. I have only access to the IPA. I read that an IPA is just a zip file with the .app and some additional files. But renaming the IPA to zip and trying to unpack it with Finder's Archiver utility does not work, it just does not complete. The according AdHoc IPAs install fine through iTunes or Xcode Organizer. I'm puzzled.

Comment: You will need the app file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429506/validate-and-submit-ipa-to-appstore-without-source

Comment: Under Windows I renamed the IPA to ZIP and extracted it. It contains the .app in the Payloads folder. I wonder why I couldn't unpack it with Finder's Archiver Tool. I'll try to upload the .app and a re-compressed version when I'm on OSX the next time.