# Titanium Built iOS App does not get Archived in XCode Orangizer

Tags: ios, xcode, titanium, appcelerator

I am using Appcelerator Titanium to build iOS apps.

I use the `ti build ... --target "dist-adhoc" ...` command to build iOS apps.  It normally works great.

Normally, the app builds and then XCode Organizer starts with the app archived in Organizer.
Today that stopped working.  The App builds, but XCode Organizer does not start.
If I start XCode Organizer manually and look in the archive the archive is not there.

The first time I did this today, it worked.  From that point forward it did not work.

Here is what I tried:

1. I tried *many* times.
2. I tried other apps (also failed).
3. I have 18GB free disk space.
4. I have rebooted my computer.
5. I have noticed that the .ipa file gets built.
6. I looked for error messages and noticed none.
7. I removed the archive that successfully built and tried to build again.
8. I noticed that the XCode/Archives/2014-mm-dd folder gets an updated timestamp, but does not get a new archive.

I like building using this method because:

From organizer I can build an OTA deploy for testing, or upload to the App Store for deliver.
I am assured that I am uploading to AppStore the exact binary that I tested OTA.

My questions are:

1. How can I debug this so I can get it to work?
2. How can I manually get the .ipa file that is built into organizer?

Comment: Any error? What if you use Application Loader to upload your IPA ? (p.s. that's the reason I stick with native Apps; 3rd party always go wrong)

Comment: I edited the question to make note that there were no errors messages during the build.  I downloaded Application Loader to see if it would help.  I use File->Open and browse to the .ipa file and it is just grey.  I do not have much interest in pursuing Application Loader because it does not seem to support OTA build like Organizer does.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: i doubt your IPA is really valid. If your IPA is valid (its header really said it's an IPA), it shouldn't appear in grey in Application Loader. Weird

Comment: Using the ipa file that was successfully loaded on my iphone I did a test.  Application Loader saw it as greyed out.  I do not see anywhere in the Application Loader .pdf that indicates that it loads .ipa files.  It says it works with packages (.itmsp).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12895317/188331 this may help you

Answer (score 0):

The AdHoc distribution creates an .ipa, not an archive. You cannot distribute it on the AppStore. It's meant to be distributed in-house. As with the development certificate, you have to manually insert each device in Apple Developer interface.