# Not sharing source code for iOS application with client

Tags: ios, app-store, source-code-protection

I have an application that will be used by multiple clients.  I do not want to share the source code with them though.  Im not an expert on iOS development, but if I build the application what can I send them that will be necessary for them to submit it to the app store, but wont be able to see the source code.  Or do I have to submit the application myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the archive yourself and send them the .ipa file which they will submit via the [application loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf).

More info in this question:
[Validate and submit ipa to AppStore without source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429506/validate-and-submit-ipa-to-appstore-without-source)

However, the easiest way, and the one that seems to be more used, is for you to log in via the clients credentials and submit the app directly.

Comment: "Selling" it to your clients will be key. Don't propose it as a limit you are trying to impose, but rather you are saving them from having to even worry about compiling and submitting to the app store.

Comment: I have scarcely had the issue with selling this process to clients, unless they have an iOS developer available, the process and the pitfalls are usually something they do not want to be bothered with.

Comment: Yea I agree but you never know, they might want to handle all billing and such themselves.

Comment: They still can do it, you are using the account to upload the archive, after which they can handle it as they see fit.